# String Interpolation from URL in the database

Tags: c#

I have a table in my database that keeps the route URL that I need to call.
For example I have this URL:

```
http://localhost/Account/Get/{id}
```

When I retrieve this value from the database, is coming into a variable. How can I do string interpolation to replace the {id} with another variable that I have with the value?

Comment: `theStringFromDb.Replace("{id}", theId)` is the most straightforward approach. Actual string interpolation requires a lot more overhead for no benefit.

Comment: In source code the compiler creates a FormattableString or call to String.Format from that string constant. I don't think you can do it runtime

Comment: Unless if you find a library to do it for you, you will need to write a tokenizer yourself. That is, if you find `string.replace()` not good enough.